# Company blog, host internally or not?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, blog

If I have a website for a company selling product(s). Is there any difference in terms of rewards/penalties from having a company blog hosted interally (for example `mycompany.com/blog`) or going externally to Blogpost, WordPress, etc. (`mycompany.blogspot.com` for example).

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Still, In first case, if you have your own domain and hosting a blog on your own site then you will cross many limitations like use of plugins, theme etc. If you are asking for a company spcially then 1st option would be better.

Comment: @John, I think there is a mistake in your link - the link points back to this very page.

Comment: Oops! Let's see if this works: [SEO implications of a blog hosted on site vs off site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2893/seo-implications-of-blog-on-site-versus-offsite/)

Comment: aha! Thanks for that - the original question was worded far better than mine was, your answer was just what I was looking for as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I described the advantages of using hosted platforms vs installed platforms in [this Webapps question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/hosted-vs-installed/8269#8269). The key point is, what are your needs at the moment.
You can start with an hosted solution, for instance `wordpress.com`, then move to a self-hosted solution later, for instance `wordpress.org`.

Many hosted blog solutions, including WordPress, Blogspot, Thumblr... offers a "custom domain name" feature. It means you can create a Blogspot blog but map it to `blog.yourcompany.com` rather than `yourcompany.blogspot.com`. This might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

The first option to host on your own domain is by far the best and most professional. Hosting at Blogspot/WordPress is like when you see companies saying *"Email us at `companyname@hotmail.com`"* - it looks cheap and unprofessional.

With your own hosting you have far more control over the site, templates, plugins and so on. One downside is that if you do not update WordPress regularly there is a *small* risk you could be hacked which would take down the whole site. Hosted services generally take care of updates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically no advantages if you host your blog elsewhere if you are easily able to host it yourself.  You should always have it on `company.com/blog`, I can't think of any exceptions.

For SEO benefit as well, have all your good content on your main domain! This means you should not have your blog on `blog.company.com`.

If you are concerned that `blog.company.com` is more memorable than `company.com/blog`, simply set up a redirect for `blog.company.com` to `company.com/blog`.

Answer (score 0):

By SEO point of view, `http://www.mycompany.com/blog` will be considered as a content of `www.mycompany.com`, while content on subdomains (for example, `http://mycompany.blogspot.com`) will be considered as a content from different domain name.

I would prefer to go with the first option, e.g. `http://www.mycompany.com/blog`.